# How to specify "own type" as return type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to specify the return type of a function to be the type of the called object?

e.g.

```
trait Foo {
    fun bar(): <??> /* what to put here? */ {
        return this
    }
}

class FooClassA : Foo {
    fun a() {}
}

class FooClassB : Foo {
    fun b() {}
}

// this is the desired effect:
val a = FooClassA().bar() // should be of type FooClassA
a.a()                     // so this would work

val b = FooClassB().bar() // should be of type FooClassB
b.b()                     // so this would work
```

In effect, this would be roughly equivalent to `instancetype` in Objective-C or `Self` in Swift.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same, but for both base calss and a subclass: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333206/kotlin-how-to-return-self-type-in-a-subclass-without-an-extension-function)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's no language feature supporting this, but you can always use recursive generics (which is the pattern many libraries use):

```
// Define a recursive generic parameter Me
trait Foo<Me: Foo<Me>> {
    fun bar(): Me {
        // Here we have to cast, because the compiler does not know that Me is the same as this class
        return this as Me
    }
}

// In subclasses, pass itself to the superclass as an argument:
class FooClassA : Foo<FooClassA> {
    fun a() {}
}

class FooClassB : Foo<FooClassB> {
    fun b() {}
}
```

Comment: Trait was deprecated in Kotlin M12, we shall use the keyword interface instead: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kotlin-m12-is-out/

Comment: Is there any way for the compiler to infer the correct behavior? Or, if it is absolutely necessary to cast, suppress the warning from the Kotlin IDE plugin: `Unchecked cast: Foo<Me> to Me`?

Comment: Bravo! Smart answer. I wonder if in 2021 there is a better one? Anyway, great answer

Comment: it would be nice if Kotlin supported referencing the implementing type using something like `Self` a la Rust, but I suppose thats a pipe dream considering this is a JVM language we're talking about... @OzShabat, there really isn't any other way than this generic soup. Frankly, such code is no different from doing wacky stuff like implementing object orientation via vtables directly in C.

Comment: @breandan nope, either kotlin isn't smart enough, or there are JVM considerations which prevent it from trying. if its the first case, things can get better. If its the latter, lament the fact that java continues to shoot itself in its foot since its inception.

Answer (score 29):

You can return something's own type with [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

```
interface ExampleInterface
// Everything that implements ExampleInterface will have this method.
fun <T : ExampleInterface> T.doSomething(): T {
    return this
}

class ClassA : ExampleInterface {
    fun classASpecificMethod() {}
}

class ClassB : ExampleInterface {
    fun classBSpecificMethod() {}
}

fun example() {
    // doSomething() returns ClassA!
    ClassA().doSomething().classASpecificMethod()
    // doSomething() returns ClassB!
    ClassB().doSomething().classBSpecificMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use an [extension method](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) to achieve the "returns same type" effect.  Here's a quick example that shows a base type with multiple type parameters and an extension method that takes a function which operates on an instance of said type:

```
public abstract class BuilderBase<A, B> {}

public fun <B : BuilderBase<*, *>> B.doIt(): B {
  // Do something
  return this
}

public class MyBuilder : BuilderBase<Int,String>() {}

public fun demo() {
  val b : MyBuilder = MyBuilder().doIt()
}
```

Since extension methods are resolved statically (at least as of M12), you may need to have the extension delegate the actual implementation to its `this` should you need type-specific behaviors.

Answer (score 7):

### Recursive Type Bound

The pattern you have shown in the question is known as *recursive type bound* in the JVM world. A recursive type is one that includes a function that uses that type itself as a type for its parameter or its return value. In your example, you are using the same type for the return value by saying `return this`.

---

### Example

Let's understand this with a simple and real example. We'll replace `trait` from your example with `interface` because `trait` is now deprecated in Kotlin. In this example, the interface `VitaminSource` returns different implementations of the sources of different vitamins.

In the following `interface`, you can see that its type parameter has itself as an upper bound. This is why it's known as recursive type bound:

**VitaminSource.kt**

```
interface VitaminSource<T: VitaminSource<T>> {
    fun getSource(): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return this as T
    }
}
```

We suppress the `UNCHECKED_CAST` warning because the compiler can't possibly know whether we passed the same class name as a type argument.

Then we extend the `interface` with concrete implementations:

**Carrot.kt**

```
class Carrot : VitaminSource<Carrot> {
    fun getVitaminA() = println("Vitamin A")
}
```

**Banana.kt**

```
class Banana : VitaminSource<Banana> {
    fun getVitaminB() = println("Vitamin B")
}
```

While extending the classes, you must make sure to pass the same class to the interface otherwise you'll get `ClassCastException` at runtime:

```
class Banana : VitaminSource<Banana>    // OK
class Banana : VitaminSource<Carrot>    // No compiler error but exception at runtime
```

**Test.kt**

```
fun main() {
    val carrot = Carrot().getSource()
    carrot.getVitaminA()

    val banana = Banana().getSource()
    banana.getVitaminB()
}
```

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to get a compile-time error?

Comment: @FelixDombek, unfortunately none that I know of. That's the only drawback of this pattern. We just need to carefully specify the same class. Maybe write a note in comments for future developers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact use case, [*scope functions*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) can be a good alternative. For the builder pattern [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) seems to be most useful because the context object is `this` and the result of the scope function is `this` as well.

Consider this example for a builder of `List` with a specialized builder subclass:

```kotlin
open class ListBuilder<E> {
    // Return type does not matter, could also use Unit and not return anything
    // But might be good to avoid that to not force users to use scope functions
    fun add(element: E): ListBuilder<E> {
        ...
        
        return this
    }

    fun buildList(): List<E> {
        ...
    }
}

class EnhancedListBuilder<E>: ListBuilder<E>() {
    fun addTwice(element: E): EnhancedListBuilder<E> {
        addNTimes(element, 2)
        return this
    }

    fun addNTimes(element: E, times: Int): EnhancedListBuilder<E> {
        repeat(times) {
            add(element)
        }
        return this
    }
}

// Usage of builder:
val list = EnhancedListBuilder<String>().apply { 
    add("a") // Note: This would return only ListBuilder
    addTwice("b")
    addNTimes("c", 3)
}.buildList()
```

However, this **only works if all methods have `this` as result**. If one of the methods actually creates a new instance, then that instance would be discarded.

---

This is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809436) to a similar question.

Answer (score -2):

```
class foo(){
fun boo():foo{
return this
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it also via extension functions.

```
class Foo
fun <T: Foo>T.someFun(): T {
    return this
}
Foo().someFun().someFun()
```