# Does Kotlin have a 'trait' type?

Tags: kotlin

I keep finding `trait` mentioned in Kotlin examples. For example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29566159/444639) uses `trait`.

Is the `trait` keyword used in Kotlin? If it is, where can I find info on it, and if it is not, was it part of the language spec at some point?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The keyword `trait` was a keyword in Kotlin but now it's removed. It was deprecated on the Kotlin M12 release.

You can find more [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/upcoming-changes-and-more/).

**Edit:** It was replaced by the `interface` keyword, see *Traits are now interfaces* in the [notes to M12 release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kotlin-m12-is-out/).

Comment: Does that page really say that `trait` itself was dropped then though? Seems to me like one of the features of `trait`s was dropped then, but not `trait` itself.