# How to refer to the implementing class in a generic interface

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I want to define an interface which would describe any tree structure of objects that contain similar objects.  An obvious implementation would be:

```
interface HasChildren {
    val children: Sequence<HasChildren>
}

class Branch(val children: Sequence<Branch>) : HasChildren
```

The more or less obvious problem with this is that while the children of a `Branch`  must always, in turn be `Branch`, that has been lost through the interface, and I have to explicitly typecast them back.

Is there a way, similar to `Self` in Swift:

```
protocol HasChildren {
    let children : Sequence<Self> { get }
}
```

to not lose the implementing class type?

Comment: This is similar to a question I answered earlier this year: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815362/1941654. References to the declared calling type can be included by using extension functions and properties. However, I think there may be more significant structural issues with the type design here and integrating it into Kotlin. What do you mean when you say that the type of the child sequence has been lost through the interface? If you're referring to retrieving children from a variable declared as a `HasChildren` object then you will be out of luck with this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) (this article is for Scala, but that shouldn't matter; I couldn't find an explanation I liked using Java or Kotlin, but the concept is exactly the same):

```
interface HasChildren<T : HasChildren<T>> {
    val children: Sequence<T>
}

class Branch(override val children: Sequence<Branch>) : HasChildren<Branch>
```

If you are familiar with C++, it's known there as ["curiously recurring template pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to take a look at `sealed class`es. A tree using them would look something like this:

```
sealed class Node<out T> {
    class Branch<T>(val left: Node<T>, val right: Node<T>) : Node<T>()
    class Leaf<T>(val value: T) : Node<T>()
    object Empty : Node<Nothing>()
}
```

`sealed class`es support checking of types with `when`:

```
when(node) {
    is Branch-> {
        // ... 
    }
    is Leaf -> {
        // ... 
    }
    is Empty -> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val tree = Branch(
          Leaf("Foo"),
          Branch(Leaf("baz"), Empty))
```

The [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) are also a good starting point.

**Edit:** AFAIK you can't do this without typecasting. I've put together a simple program with a hack though:

```
object Playground {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val tree = Branch(
                Leaf("Foo"),
                Branch(Leaf("baz"), Empty))

        // works
        val foo = tree.left.castTo<Node.Leaf<String>>()

        println(foo)

        // oops
        tree.left.castTo<Node.Empty>()
    }

}


sealed class Node<out T> {
    data class Branch<T>(val left: Node<T>, val right: Node<T>) : Node<T>()
    data class Leaf<T>(val value: T) : Node<T>()
    object Empty : Node<Nothing>()
}

inline fun <reified U : Node<Any>> Node<Any>.castTo(): U {
    require(this is U) {
        "Node '${this::class.simpleName}' is not of required type '${U::class.simpleName}'."
    }
    return this as U
}
```

I'd really like to see a more robust solution because this is rather ugly, but I was not able to figure out a better solution so far (I also have this problem from time to time).

Comment: The question isn't really about how to represent a tree, it's about how to represent an interface that references items of the implementing class (as opposed to the interface itself)

Comment: This way you can check the children's types safely like in your `Branch` example (with the `when` construct). Did I miss something? I'm not familiar with Swift.

Comment: Ignore the specifics of the question, ie., Trees and Branches and Children.  They were to give an example of a basic problem which is how to declare that an interface method (or property) returns an object of the *implementing* class type, not the *interface* type.

Comment: Oh, I see. What is your use case? I'm asking this to prevent an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).