# Kotlin - how to return "self type" in a subclass? (without an extension function)

Tags: kotlin, generics, subclass, self-type

Let's have these classes:

```
class A {
    fun foo(): A = this
}

class B: A() {
    fun bar() { ... }
}
```

Now I would like Kotlin to detect when I call `foo` on `B`, and give me the result typed as `B`. So that I can write:

```
B().foo().bar()
```

With kotlin 1.4.20, this is not possible - it would need an explicit cast to `B` after `foo()`.

Perhaps it could be handled by the compiler, if it clearly sees that the function returns `this`. Or maybe we could hint it explicitly...

```
class A {
    fun <Self> foo(): Self = this
}
```

I can't use extension function because I need the Java classes to have the properties.

I have read this [Kotlin forum thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371/61) on that topic, however I didn't see this case being solved. But maybe it's implied. Either way, it's not implemented at the moment.

One more nice article [here](https://medium.com/@jerzy.chalupski/emulating-self-types-in-kotlin-d64fe8ea2e62).

I have read this SO question [How to specify "own type" as return type in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565043/how-to-specify-own-type-as-return-type-in-kotlin) and I have tried the "recursive type" approach, but it doesn't work if I want to have the type on the subclasses as well as base class:

```
Type parameter Me of 'HasStatus' has inconsistent values: BaseClass, Subclass
```

Is there any other trick to persuade Kotlin to return the type of `this` if a method returns `this`?