# Is it possible to have a field with a generic type that refers to the actual runtime type of the containing class?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm fiddling around with this code where I have a base class `Node` which can be extended:

```
open class Node
class SubNode : Node()
```

Now, I have a `Behavior` class that can be attached to a node, and when this attachment happens, the behavior object is invoked:

```
open class Behavior {
    fun attach(node: Node) {
        println("Behavior was attached to a node")
    }
}

open class Node {
    var behavior: Behavior? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            value.attach(this)
        }
}
```

This works, but could this be generified in such way that the type of the `attach` method would always refer to the actual type of the attached `Node`? For instance, if the `Behavior` class was extended like this:

```
open class Behavior<NodeType: Node> {
    open fun attach(node: NodeType) {

    }
}

class SubBehavior : Behavior<SubNode>() {
    override fun attach(node: SubNode) {

    }
}
```

I've tried various ways of setting up the types in `Node` class, but can't figure any other way than passing the actual subclass type to the base class (which seems rather cumbersome):

```
open class Node<SubType: Node> {
    var behavior: Behavior<SubType>? = null
}

class SubNode : Node<SubNode>()
```

Is there a way to do this in any other way?

Comment: Could you please show how you intend to use `Behaviour` inside the `Node`? And the `node` inside `Behaviour`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need are [self types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565043/how-to-specify-own-type-as-return-type-in-kotlin), which don't exist in Kotlin (at least, not yet).

Using recursive generics like you did is the most common way around the problem.

That said, I have trouble understanding your use case here for intertwining these 2 classes together this way. Like how is `behaviour` used inside your node, etc.